# Script to remove seams from cube

Tags: python, uv

I have cube object with one texture on UV map.
[image]
Texture perfectly fits object but it renders abt 1px dark seams. Need help to get rid of these seams preferably by using bpy.
[image]

Comment: Is it the texture include the seam?

Comment: On first image you can see texture. When it's wrapped on the cube there are natural seams. But I can't close them

Comment: I've created texture file by perfectly stiching together 6 separate images, there are no gaps or BG defined

Comment: are you sure those are seams and not just the edges overlaid?  Have you tried rendering your cube to see if the black lines show up in a render?

Comment: Yes these seams are visible in render